# Number of real solutions of quadratic equation

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory, quadratics

I have the following question that puzzles me: How do I determine the number of non-trivial real solutions to the general equation $ax^2 + bxy + cy^2 = 0$ (up to a scalar)?

My attempt was to fix $y \neq 0$ and then see how many non-complex solution the quadratic equation has for $x$. However, I was hoping that there would be a more elegant way to do this.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: If you assume $y\neq 0$, set $t = \frac{x}{y}$. Find the number of real zeros of $at^2 + bt + c$ and draw your conclusions.

Comment: Hint: $ax^2+bxy+cy^2=a(x+(b/2a)y)^2+(c-(b^2/4a))y^2$. (Here I assume $a \neq 0$. You can do the analogous thing assuming $c \neq 0$. If both are zero then the question is quite straightforward.)

Answer (score 0):

HINT: $$ax^2+bxy+cy^2=0$$ $$c(y^2+\frac{b}{c}xy+\frac{a}{c}x^2)=0$$ $$c(y+m_1x)(y+m_2x)=0$$ where $m_1+m_2=-\frac{b}{c}$ and $m_1m_2=\frac{a}{c}$

Hope this helps.

Comment: If such $m_1,m_2$ exist, that is.

Comment: @Ian Yes it's an assumption.